# How to return a templated derived class instead of base class in an overridden function?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, return-type

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {};

class C
{
    virtual A<int> func() = 0;
};

class D : public C
{
    virtual B<int> func() override
    {
        return B<int>{};
    }
};
```

Here `B` inherits from `A` and the template argument is `int` for both of the return values. Why can't I just return `B<int>` instead of `A<int>`?

Answer (score 1):

When declaring B, you must inherit from an actual class, not a template:

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {};
```

The second issue is that you cannot change the signature of `func()` when overriding it in class `D`. However, once that's fixed, you will be able to return `B<int>{}` as expected.

Edit: a third problem pointed out by @Josh Wilson is that you will not get the behavior of a `B` from the return value of `func()` because it specifies an `A` returned by value. You need to return a pointer to `A<int>` for polymorphism to apply.

Comment: That was a mistake. I changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As merlinND pointed out, you have to inherit from `class A<T>`. But it will still fail unless you return a pointer or reference to B instead of a value type. The following will compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {};

class C
{
    virtual A<int>* func() = 0;
};

class D : public C
{
    virtual B<int>* func() override
    {
        return new B<int>{};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

B D::func() cannot be an override of AC::func(), because the return type of those two function are different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> If the function `Derived::f` overrides a function `Base::f`, their return types must either be the same or be covariant.

There are 3 conditions to be all satisfied for two types to be covariant, and one of them is that they need to be either a pointer type or a reference type.

`A<int>` and `B<int>` are neither the same type nor covariant types, which implies that you cannot use `B<int>` as the return type of your overridden method.

Please also notice that you don't have to use `virtual` specifier in your overridden method.

Moreover, as also other people noticed, the following will work and return an `A<int>`-typed object:

```
A<int> func() override
{
    return B<int>{};
}
```

But you should avoid it. In fact, after a `B<int>` object is created, it will be *sliced* into an `A<int>` type, for the reasons we have seen, meaning your object type will effectively be simply `A<int>`, and not a `B<int>`'s instance. This means that you uselessly created a `B<int>` instance when you could have just created an `A<int>`.

If you need a `B<int>`, you'll need to return either a pointer or a reference.